# How to install db2-client on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: database

on RHEL Desktop:

```
rpm -aq | grep db2
db2-client-9.7-1.x86_64
```

There is the db2-client package, OK. But How can I install db2-client to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop?

http://packages.ubuntu.com/

didn't gave anything related.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all try to found out that the client has `deb` packages, because `rpm`s won't work in Ubuntu. But I guess only RHEL will be supported.